# Data frame typecasting entire column to character from numeric

Tags: r, casting, dataframe, numeric

Suppose I have a `data.frame` that's completely `numeric`. If I make one entry of the first column a `character` (for example), then the entire first column will become `character`.

**Question**: How do I reverse this. That is, how do I make it such that any `character` objects inside the `data.frame` that are "obviously" `numeric` objects are forced to be `numeric`?

MWE:

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50),10))
is(test[3,1])
test[1,1] <- "TEST"
is(test[3,1])
print(test)
```

So my goal here would be to go FROM the way that `test` is now, TO a state of affairs where `test[2:10]` is `numeric`. So I guess I'm asking for a function that does this over an entire `data.frame`.

Comment: A column in an R dataframe can only have one type, so if you put a string in like "TEST" it's forced to change that entire column to a string. You can do `test$X1 <- as.numeric(test$X1)`, but note that since "TEST" is not "obviously numeric" it will be converted to `NA`. Otherwise, you could make sure things were numeric *before* assigning them to the data frame: `test[1, 1] <- as.numeric("TEST")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is you cannot.
As was mentioned in the comments, in a data frame, all elements of a column must have the same mode.

If you would like to specifically find the values that are "number like" you can use the following (where `vec` here would be, say, a data frame column)

```
  vec[!is.na(as.numeric((vec)))]
```

You can then convert these, but unfortunately you cannot put the converted values back into the same column. As as you do, they will be coerced back to `character`

---

As for a function that can convert the whole dataframe to numeric (realizing that isolating  specific entries as exceptions is not possible), you can use `sapply`

```
  sapply(dataFrameName, as.numeric)
```

Comment: Or we could use `data.matrix(...)`

Comment: Sure, but if you have columns that look like numbers but are in fact factors, `data.matrix` might give unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to have vectors of type list in a data.frame, and the list can contain any type of object except functions as long as it is of the same length as the other columns in the data.frame, e.g.:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(numbers=1:3)
mydataframe$mylist <- list(1, 'plum', 5)
mydataframe
#  numbers mylist
#1       1      1
#2       2   plum
#3       3      5
sapply(mydataframe, typeof)
#  numbers    mylist 
#"integer"    "list" 
sapply(mydataframe$mylist, typeof)
#[1] "double"    "character" "double"
```