# Can you recode all variables in a dataframe in one go?

Tags: r, class, variables

I would like to batch recode all variables in my dataframe. Some of the vars have the wrong class, and I want to make all of them numeric. Is that possible? Or should I do it variable after variable?

I get an error when I try something simple like

```
    df <- as.numeric(df)
```

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)` (and then possibly `as.matrix(df)`), but of course you should investigate why you have wrong classes and fix the root cause.

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13677856/1705441) using `sapply(df, as.numeric)`

Comment: Indeed I also just found it! (using some other search terms..) - thanks for the answer.

Comment: You need to beware of doing `as.numeric` on a `factor` class columns. It will give you wrong result